# Make a list from the other different type of list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `List<A>` of data, and wanna store it to the other list(`List<B>`).
any suggestion to make it possible?

Comment: Is there any relation between A and B ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at the Javadoc - maybe the second method you come to will be useful.

Comment: the purpose of using A or B is the same, but B is an extension.

Comment: There's an addAll function on Collection that will allow you to add all members of another collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the Collections.copy(ListA, ListB) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List%3C?%20super%20T%3E,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29), or even, if you're working with ArrayLists: [ListB = ListA.clone()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29)

Comment: good point, will try later